# WordPress Logo File Not Uploading with Custom Theme Panel

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a WordPress website with custom theme panel options following [this guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-wordpress-theme-settings-page-with-the-settings-api/).

```
function logo_display()
{
    ?>
        <input type="file" name="logo" /> 
        <?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>
   <?php
}

function handle_logo_upload()
{
    if(!empty($_FILES["demo-file"]["tmp_name"]))
    {
        $urls = wp_handle_upload($_FILES["logo"], array('test_form' => FALSE));
        $temp = $urls["url"];
        return $temp;   
    }
        elseif(isset($_FILES["logo"]) && empty($_FILES['logo']['name'])){
        $urls = $_POST["ologo"];
        return $urls;
    }
        return $option;
}

function display_theme_panel_fields()
{
    add_settings_section("section", "All Settings", null, "theme-options");

    add_settings_field("logo", "Logo", "logo_display", "theme-options", "section");  

    register_setting("section", "logo", "handle_logo_upload");

}

add_action("admin_init", "display_theme_panel_fields");
```

The file upload displays properly on the front end, however when I upload the file and click submit the page processes and reloads with no logo updated - Media Library is also empty confirming no successful upload.

Normally I would check file permissions but I'm developing this locally on WP Local, and when I test uploading files to the Media Library directly it works fine.

I don't have the option of using the built in WP Theme Customizer custom logo functionality.. it has to be built into the custom theme panel options.

Is there something wrong with my code causing it not to upload the file properly? I can't figure it out. Thank you!

EDIT: I've learned this guide/code is deprecated, but is there still a way to do it this way without using the_custom_logo()? I am instructed to build it this way as a coding test ironically